# jQuery Slide not Looping Back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this simple Slideshow on the Internet, but the problem is that it doesn't repeat itself.

What I mean, is that it goes from 1 to 2, but doesn't go back to 1. What do I have to modify in the jQuery? Thanks, this is my first post.

JavaScript Code:

```
function slideSwitch() {
var mylenght = 5;
var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');
if ($active.length == mylenght) $active = $("#slideshow IMG:first")
// use this to pull the images in the order they appear in the markup
var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

// uncomment the 3 lines below to pull the images in random order

// var $sibs  = $active.siblings();
// var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * $sibs.length );
// var $next  = $( $sibs[ rndNum ] );

$active.addClass('last-active');

$next.css({opacity: 0.0})
    .addClass('active')
    .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active last-active');
    });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Comment: do you have any js fiddle for this..?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r37cR/

Comment: your jsfiddle isn't working, but a quick guess to make it loop would be to reset `mylenght` when `$active.length == mylenght`

Comment: @Sabe How do I reset it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var mylenght = 4;
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ($('#slideshow IMG').index($active) == mylenght - 1) 
        $next = $("#slideshow IMG:first")
    else
        $next = $active.next();


    $next.addClass('active').css({opacity: 0.0}).animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000); 
    $active.removeClass('active').css({opacity: 1.0}).animate({opacity: 0}, 1000);
}
```

Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/K62DX/

Comment: @user3621073 pl find fiddle link in answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. But the first image doesn't load in time enough